# Fetching PHP Data with Javascript and assign it to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I've got a php script with collects data from a server and displays it in an array and after that as a json with the function.

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Now I want to access that array with my javascript and display it. It should be saved in a var as an array so it should look like:

```
 data = [ "xxxx" , "ssss",];
```

But I guess I can simply put in my function which gets the array data instead so it'd be:

```
data = myfunction ;
```

What I've tried so far:

```
 function reqListener () {
     console.log(this.responseText);
         }

        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); //New request object
      oReq.onload = function() {


       };
        oReq.open("get", "http://myserver.com/myscript.php", true);

oReq.send();
```

and

```
function getdata(url) {
jQuery.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://myserver.com/myscript.php/",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (response) {
                var JSONArray = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                connsole.log(JSONArray);
                }
        });
    }
```

But none seems to work and I get displayed 'undefined' instead of my arrays.
Would be really great if somebody has some ideas on that and can help me out.

Edit:
Since we are getting nowhere here's my php code:

```
<?php 
 error_reporting(0);
 $html = file_get_contents("url here");

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

 $tbodyRows = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'tbody' )
             ->item( 0 ) // grab first tbody
             ->getElementsByTagName( 'tr' );

$result = array();
foreach( $tbodyRows as $tbodyRow )
{
  $result[] = $tbodyRow->getElementsByTagName( 'td' )
                     ->item( 2 ) // grab 3rd column
                     ->nodeValue;
 }


echo json_encode($result);
 ?>
```

Comment: If you open `http://myserver.com/myscript.php` in the browser, what's the output?

Comment: It's an array and after that the json encode. First in my php I have       $result = array(); and at the end of my script I have var_dump( $result );
echo json_encode($result);

Comment: I asked you about the output because it should be a valid JSON, so if you go to `http://myserver.com/myscript.php` you should see something like: `{"key":"value"}`. If you have a `var_dump`, then that's probably what's causing the problem since you're printing something like: `array(1) { ["key"]=> string(5) "value" }{"key":"value"}` which isn't valid JSON

Comment: yep I'm printing what you've stated. { ["key"]=> string(5) "value" } But with the echo json_encode I'm printing a correct array format [ "value", "value2"]

Comment: The problem is, when the server returns the response, the response is not only `["value", "value2"]` but `array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "value" [1]=> string(6) "value2" }` and `["value", "value2"]`, because of the `var_dump`. So you'll try to decode a string that isn't really a JSON. Comment out the `var_dump` line and let me know if it works. Also, if you could go in your browser to `http://myserver.com/myscript.php` and tell me the exact text you see, it would be helpful

Comment: I still get undefined printed. The PHP output without the var_dump looks like the following:   ["value1","value2","value3","value4","value5"," ......" ] It is about 2000 values.

Comment: Ok, let's try something else, change the call to `json_encode` to `json_encode(array(1))`. If it's working right, the whole output should be `[1]`. If you see anything else besides that, you have something else printing data, comment out those lines

Comment: Yep output is [1]. Just noticing .. does that might help you that I get a bunch or warnings before the output (mostly tag invalid) ? But it's only working for the php script not for the js script, still getting 'undefined' printed instead of 1

Comment: The whole output must be `[1]`, if you have warnings then the whole output isn't valid JSON. You could turn off warnings temporally by writing `error_reporting(0);` at the beginning of your script

Comment: Okay, I got the [1] output now, but js still prints undefined.

Comment: Put `console.log(response);` in the `success` function and see if it prints anything besides `[1]`. It's possible there's some HTML hiding there

Comment: nope nothing in the console

Comment: Nothing? Wait, the `undefined` you mentioned being logged in the browser's console is being printed by the line which logs the `JSONArray` or from where?

Comment: The undefined was being printed by my php script before the array

Comment: But didn't you tell me that all the output from the PHP script was `[1]`? So it really is `undefined[1]`?

Comment: Sorry, the php script puts out [1] but the js still puts out undefined

Comment: Read the comment I wrote on my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function getdata(url) {
  console.log('Started');
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://myserver.com/myscript.php",
    dataType: "text",
    error: function (xhr) {
      console.log('Error',xhr.status);
    },
    success: function (response) {
      console.log('Success',response);
    }
  });
}
```

Open the browser's console, and let me know about its contents. If you don't see `Error` or `Success`, your code isn't actually executing

Comment: Ok there's nothing in the console and my code is not executing. But the animation which I want to display from the Js Code works. It's only the values not coming up and instead I get 'undefined' . What should I do ?

Comment: It seems like you're not calling the `getdata` function. Try putting `getdata();` right after the function definition to call it immediately

Comment: I think the problem is more about storing the result from the getdata function into a variable. What would be the correct syntax for that if the variable is "chinese" . Would it be   ' var chinese = getdata(); ' ?

Comment: No, the function `getdata`, as defined, doesn't return anything. If makes an asynchronous call to `http://myserver.com/myscript.php`, registers the actions for `error` and `success` and then returns. Whenever the server responds, one of those actions will be triggered so one of the `console.log` statements should be executed. You can call the function from anywhere in your script, or even from the console, just by typing `getdata()`. I updated the code so there's a third `console.log` so we can tell if the function has started

Comment: Ok that's weird. When I try to call the function from the console it returns . 
   VM8131:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: getdata is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1 .  Also still not logging anything.

Comment: Where are you defining the `getdata` function? It should be correctly defined as a Javascript function. Try copy/pasting it in the console and then calling it. I have to go to sleep, but maybe that'll help you find the problem

Comment: Im defining it in my javascript and tried it at the end and at the beginning although that doesnt matter... When I copy/paste the whole function in the console it still returns' < undefined'  I have defined it exactly as you provided it in your code

Comment: ok lol nevermind i've got it working with logs in the console

Comment: Maybe you should share your solution so others can learn from it

Comment: I used your code but there were problems with my javascript. Because ajax is asynchronus and I wanted them to load synchronus

Answer (score 1):

I have done a similar thing earlier. I will describe it and I wish it will help you.

In the following code (get_categories.php), I am retrieving data from the database and add them to an array. Then return it by encoding as a JSON.

```
$sql = "SELECT category_name FROM category;";
$dataArray = [];
$result = $connection->query($sql);
if ($result) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dataArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($dataArray);
}
```

Then in my Javascript code, I can get the data as follows.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/get_categories.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (categories) {
        for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
            console.log(categories[i]);
        }                
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Error handling code
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tested it again by initializing the array like `$dataArray = ["A","B"];`.
Then accessed like this.

`dataType: "json",`
`success: function (categories) {`
`for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {`
`console.log(categories[i]);`
`}`

**Please note that there is a small mistake in previous code. `categories[i].category_name` should be `categories[i]`.**

Comment: Please note that I have corrected the mistake in the code.

Comment: I didnt know what to do with that. I've tried changing my code with yours but I keep getting the same 'undefined' as before. Maybe the problem is not the array itself but declaring it ? I currently have it like this :                      
  printing = getdata ;

Comment: Can you post the updated function which is handling the response?